# JsPath and JsFile for vue-i18n-generator in Laravel 5.7 without "assets" folder in resource directory

Tags: vue-i18n

As vue-i18n-generator documentation says, the configuration paths changed in Laravel 5.7, so i changed the path in the vue-i18n-generator.php. When i use artisan command vue-i18n:generate, it give me an error saying that the path is not found. It seems that the generator using the old path. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the path in 'app/config/vue-i18n-generator.php'